# Sort elements with jquery sort() function fails on webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sorting, webkit

I have this part of function to sort elements by a number. This number is taken from a `data-ranking` attribute of the element to sort:

```
$(".tab_entry").sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(a.dataset.ranking) < parseFloat(b.dataset.ranking)
}).appendTo('div.active');
```

**Now the problem:** This works perfectly on Firefox 24 but not in Chrome 28 (Sort fails, order got wrong), and does nothing on Safari 5.1.7 and IE 10.

Have anyone get a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a sort function listed in it's API.

You may need to convert your elements to an array first, so you can use the browser's native sort function:

```
var sortedArray = $(".tab_entry").toArray().sort(function(a,b){ ... })
```

Furthermore (and perhaps more importantly), the sort function should return a number, not just true/false: [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
function(a,b) {
    //Return the difference in the rankings.
    //May need to switch the terms depending on what ordering you want.
    return parseFloat(a.dataset.ranking) - parseFloat(b.dataset.ranking)
}
```

Comment: I will try this converting the elements to array. I will be back with feedback in few seconds. Thanks

Comment: Trying this gets error. Syntax Error and `appendTo` is not a function

Comment: You'd need to turn the resulting array back into a jQuery object.
`$(sortedArray).appendTo('div.active')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
return parseFloat(a.dataset.ranking) - parseFloat(b.dataset.ranking);
```

This will return a negative number if `a` is smaller than `b`, which will place `a` before `b` and vice-versa. If both values are equal, it will return `0` and the order will remain the same since the sort is unstable.

Comment: This worked for Firefox, Chrome and Safari. IE doesn't work. It does nothing. I will try with ThinTim solution

Comment: @ErickLeónBolinaga Well that means the sort plugin that you are using is bugged as it's not truly cross-browser. Are you using it's lastest version?

Comment: Using jquery 1.9.1 and browsers: Firefox 24, Chrome 28, Safari 5.1.7, and IE 10. The exactly code I am using is this. `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".tab_entry").sort(function(a,b){
    return parseFloat(b.dataset.ranking) - parseFloat(a.dataset.ranking)
   }).appendTo('div.active');`